# Installing ApkStudio on Linux(Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering

I tried installing APK Studio on my Ubuntu 15.04 machine but keep getting this error message:

```
 g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DAPP_REV_SHORT=\"0978cd4\" -DAPP_REV_LONG=\"0978cd4653fcfed5601d57b8e0f7cfade7f64d7a\" -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -o adb.o src/adb.cpp
In file included from ./include/adb.h:5:0,
                 from src/adb.cpp:1:
./include/process.h:4:30: fatal error: QRegularExpression: No such file or directory
 #include <QRegularExpression>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:474: recipe for target 'adb.o' failed
make: *** [adb.o] Error 1.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using an unsupported QT version, check your version with:

```
$ qmake -version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Make sure you have GCC 4.6+, QT 5.2+
On Ubuntu, you can run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake qt5-default libqt5opengl5-dev
$ qmake -version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Running make again should build ApkStudio with no errors.